# Wrong sorting decimal values tablesorter script

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I have problem while sorting decimal values table sorter grid.
When I try to sort distance values in the table the distance sort as follows :

```
distance
0.35
0.76
1.36
1.75
10.36
100.66
2.33

$(document).ready(function() {
// extend the default setting to always include the zebra widget.
$.tablesorter.defaults.widgets = ['zebra'];
// extend the default setting to always sort on the first column
$.tablesorter.defaults.sortList = [[0,0]];
$.tablesorter.defaults.debug=true;
  $("table#list").tablesorter();
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("table#list").tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
    });
```

Can any one tell me what's the solution to prevent wrong sorting ?

Comment: I guess this happens because the values are compared as strings but should be parsed as numbers before comparing them.

Comment: Read the manual. http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-parsers.html

Comment: Having looked into this it should recognise decimal columns automatically. Can you set up a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate your problem? It may be something in your html that is confusing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the sorter to `digit` in the header option:

```
$(function() {
  $("table#list").tablesorter({
    widgets  : ['zebra'],
    sortList : [[0,0]]
    headers  : {
      0 : { sorter : 'digit' }
    }
  }).tablesorterPager({
    container: $("#pager")
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I tried `<th class="{sorter: 'text'}">...</th>` but it was ignored. Thanks for this version which works

Comment: @mplungjan That code will only work if the metadata plugin is included. Or you could check out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) which allows you to set the class name in the header `<th class="sorter-text">`.

Comment: I do not see anything about including a plugin [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-parsers.html) - and the link to the metadata plugin on your fork is dead ---------------------------

 However do you by any chance know the answer to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933681/changing-the-way-table-is-sorted-jquery-tablesorter/13934321#13934321

Comment: If you look at the page source you'll see the metadata plugin is being loaded: `<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.metadata.js"></script>`. Which link is broken? Oh and the metadata plugin is included with the download of tablesorter.