# Changing the way table is sorted jquery tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using jquery tablesorter to sort my table. I've tried to google my question, didn't find what I was looking for.

I've got a table which content changes dynamically so I want to change the way items are sorted.

One case I've got table populated with text which can be sorter with default `.tablesorter()` and I've got another case where digits are in table so I need to invoke tablesorter like this :

```
$('table').tablesorter({
        headers : { 
                0 : {sorter:'digit'},
                1 : {sorter:'digit'},
                2 : {sorter:'digit'},
                3 : {sorter:'digit'}
        }
    });
```

I have a method that does reload to table switching between numbers/text in table content, how can I change the way table is sorted.

In the example (pseudocode):

```
function reloadTableData
if table contains numbers user this tablesorter (I have a way to know if table contains numbers) 
$('table').tablesorter({
            headers : { 
                    0 : {sorter:'digit'},
                    1 : {sorter:'digit'},
                    2 : {sorter:'digit'},
                    3 : {sorter:'digit'}
            }
        });
if table contains text use ordinary table sorter 
$('table').tablesorter();
end
```

I can reload table data n times with either text/numbers.

I've tried the following :

```
function initTablesorter(n) {

    switch(n)
    {
    case "number":
      digitTableSorter();
      break;
    case "text":
     defaultTableSorter();
      break;
    default:

    }
}

function digitTableSorter(){
$('table').tablesorter({
        headers : { 
                0 : {sorter:'digit'},
                1 : {sorter:'digit'},
                2 : {sorter:'digit'},
                3 : {sorter:'digit'}
        }
    });
}

function defaultTableSorter(){
$('table').tablesorter();
}
```

Needless to say it's not working, I hope someone did something like this before, I'm stuck for some time now.

Comment: So is it not working beacuse you are reinitialising tablesorter on a table? You may try to unbind tablesorter before rebinding it. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171530/remove-jquery-tablesorter-from-table

Comment: @Simon hey thanks it worked can you reply and I'd accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is it not working because you are reinitialising tablesorter on a table? You may try to unbind tablesorter before rebinding it.

```
$('table')
 .unbind('appendCache applyWidgetId applyWidgets sorton update updateCell')
 .removeClass('tablesorter')
 .find('thead th')
 .unbind('click mousedown')
 .removeClass('header headerSortDown headerSortUp');
```

Have a look at [Remove jQuery tablesorter from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171530/remove-jquery-tablesorter-from-table).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this - You will need [MetatData plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-metadata) to get the th classes to like `"{sorter: 'digit'}"`

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html

```
 $("#trigger-link").click(function() { 
    // set sorting column and direction, this will sort on the first and third column the column index starts at zero 
    var sorting = [[0,0],[2,0]]; 
    // sort on the first column 
    $("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]); 
    // return false to stop default link action 
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: If you go to the [Download](http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html#Download) section of the documentation, you'll see this message: jQuery Metadata 2.1 (3,7kb Required for setting inline options). You'll see that the "inline options" link there refers to the metadata examples.